# PHP PDO UPDATE query with bind params

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
$sth = "UPDATE `users` SET users_password VALUES (:hash) WHERE users_id = $users_id";
$q = $conn->prepare($sth);
$q->execute(array(':hash'=>$hash));
```

But Im getting the following:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES ('$2y$12$Ao46iC7W9Lj8FFfSmAaeoeQs9O.3QRVtDbHAyvpzH90YIUN61ma8i') WHERE us' at line 1'
```

Any ideas?

(and yes the code isn't in a try, catch block yet just experimenting at them moment with a few things)

Comment: The `VALUES` clause does belong in an `INSERT` query, not in an `UPDATE`.

Comment: Why not bind users_id ?

Comment: hey @S.Visser I can do yes thank you. I'm new to PDO so just feeling my way at the moment and trying different things out before I try and produce any meaningful code/projects with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
$sth = "UPDATE `users` SET users_password VALUES (:hash) WHERE users_id = $users_id";
```

to

```
$sth = "UPDATE `users` SET users_password = :hash WHERE users_id = $users_id";
```

Comment: why downvote? atleast explain. Because this answer is correct.

Comment: it wasn't me who down voted :) it worked perfectly thank you. I think it was the Mario guy from above sadly people like him in the PHP community are not here to help but to simply show how far 'Superior' they are at coding than new guys like me without offering any help.